# Calculate with string jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, variables

So I've got a span that goes like this:

```
 <span>1</span>
```

Now I want to do something like this (plus it)

```
 $(this).next("span").text($(this).next("span").text + 1);
```

But it won't work. You're seeing where I'm going though, right? I want to make the number in the string or variable go one higher.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should accept an answer if you found one helpful :)

Comment: I will, I just can't accept one in 5 minutes, just posted another question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('span').html( parseInt( $('span').html(),10 ) + 1 );
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kefh3/)**

Comment: @Schart If this answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the outlined checkmark below the down arrow.

Comment: @Schart: The main thing to realise here, is that, unlike PHP (which I presume you are coming from, given the `$nexttext` thing in your example comment) - JS does not automatically convert variables from text to numbers, you have to do so manually using a set of conversion functions, of which `parseInt()` is one, `parseFloat()` is another.

Comment: Okay good to know! :) (I haven't accepted yet because I had to wait 5 minutes before accepting another answer)

Answer (score 4):

Try the JavaScript `parseInt()` function. Be sure you properly handle error cases, as in someone putting an invalid integer value into the span.

Comment: I tried : '$nexttext = parseInt($(this).next("span"));' and then '$(this).next("span").text($nexttext + 1);' but it didn't work. It returns NaN

Comment: @Schart `$nexttext` doesn't contain text, but an object.  That is why it didn't work.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the parseInt thing though, it will definitely help in the future! :)